# AttributeError: '_BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'classes'

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

<kbd>here is my code :</kbd>

```
`test ='C:/Users/..'
test = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(test, shuffle=True, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, image_size=IMG_SIZE)
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(160, 160, 3))
test_data = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./127.5, offset=-1)(inputs)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

prediksi = modelKu.predict(test)
y_pred = np.argmax(prediksi, axis=1)

print("============================Confusion Matrix=====================")
print(confusion_matrix(test.classes,y_pred))`
```

<kbd>the eror is :</kbd>

```
`AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [12], line 7
      4 y_pred = np.argmax(prediksi, axis=1)
      6 print("============================Confusion Matrix=====================")
----> 7 print(confusion_matrix(test.classes,y_pred))`
```

AttributeError: '_BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'classes'

<kbd>How can I solve the error?
Thanks.</kbd>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.